# Circumvent missing 32bit build agent for TFS2017

Tags: jenkins, 32bit-64bit

The TFS2017 supports build agents only on a 64bit OS and TFS2017 does not support the (32bit-)agents from TFS2015 anymore. 
However, we need to run our test code on our 32bit OS to stay as similar to the production environment as possible. :/

We consider using Jenkins as a TFS triggered agent to execute the build and run the NUnit test steps on the 32bit OS, but it sounds like a high administrative load.

Does anyone have experiences to circumvent the missing 32bit TFS agent? Or do you see any other possiblitiy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your project on build agent server and run test on test agents server. Test agent could be install on both 64 and 32 bit system. Make sure the build agent and test agent are connecting.

Create a build definition all these steps:

1. Nuget Restore
2. Build solution
3. Copy Files (Copy to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`)
4. Publish Artifacts to a share folder or Server
5. Visual Studio Test Agent Deploy: Deploy the test agents to your 32 bit server.
6. Run Functional tests: The `Test Drop location` is where you publish your code to.

For more details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/set-up-continuous-testing-builds

Note:

If the test agent can't be deploy successfully, you could install it manually. [Download from here.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents) Remember to restart the server after install test agent.